# using gmail api to filter out emails from some format

Tags: node.js, email, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying out gmail api and having hard time with filters.
I want to exclude some emails,
something like filtering out emails sent to "myname@mycompany.com",
having no luck finding anything in gmail api docs.

I am using nodejs client and constructing query like this.

```
    const result = await gmail.users.messages.list({
      auth: oauth2Client,
      userId: "me",
      q: `in:sent after:2021/09/01`
    })
```

does gmail api have something like not:myname@mycompany.com
or something like exclude:myname@mycompany.com
or is this not possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you append `-keyword` at query

```js
const result = await gmail.users.messages.list({
      auth: oauth2Client,
      userId: "me",
      q: `in:sent after:2021/09/01 -myname@mycompany.com`
    });
```

Comment: Works great! thanks for the answer! follow up question if you don't mind - can I turn that query into something like exclude any emails from @mycompany.com?
would just adding -@mycompany.com work?

Comment: yes, you can exclude any keyword with -keyword rule like google search

Comment: thank you so much!